# How to run a process as administrator user from a non-admin application

Tags: c#, console-application

I would like to know if there is a way to run a process as administrator user from a non-admin application, i tried using this :

```
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Verb = "runas",
            FileName = "notepad.exe",
            UserName = username,
            Password = pass,
            Domain = Environment.MachineName,
            UseShellExecute = true,
        };
        Process.Start(psi);
```

I get this error :

System.InvalidOperationException : 'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false to start a process as a user'

I can't set ShellExecute to true and use username and password, but I need to set it to true to set Verb to "runas".

Comment: You get an error? Are we to guess what that error is?

Comment: Something like "Set UseShellExecute to false to start a process as another user'

Comment: Please copy and paste the _exact error_ and include it in your question. See [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)

Comment: With underlying Win32 ShellExecute you don't need password. Not sure about C# parameters; simplest Win32 call looks like: 'ShellExecute(NULL, "runas", progPath, " -u", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);' It starts the executable (progPath) with command-line parameter '-u'.

Answer (score -4):

I have the solution : `var password = "true";`

Best regards Tommy, call me if you need a job ;)